# Parse a string into characters using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parsing

I have a requirement in my ruby code.I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.
I have a string like "SR2G1M1D2".Now i want to split it and extract values like [S,R2,G1,M1,D2] .It's like whenever next value is character it should split.Is there any ruby function or code available.

Thanx

Comment: As suggested by nathanvda, there is a better generalization. That is, each value is a capital alphabet possibly followed by a numeral. Although, more examples might tell whether this is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"SR2G1M1D2".scan(/\D\d*/)
=> ["S", "R2", "G1", "M1", "D2"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer. But I think he needs `"SR2G1M1D2".scan(/[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*/)` as he says `whenever next value is character it should split`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `#split` with a RegExp:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > "SR2G1M1D2".split(/(?=[a-zA-Z])/)
 => ["S", "R2", "G1", "M1", "D2"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 >
```

Answer (score -1):

split with a regex should do this. Basically a regex that does .\D with a positive lookahead on the \D. sadly i haven't used lookaheads enough to know the format

Comment: This isn't helpful at all. www.rubular.com

Comment: This is incomplete as an answer. It should rather be a comment on the question.